# Two byte arrays of identical value aren't equal

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

While writing a program, I recently came across an odd problem. Two byte arrays of eight values, with identical values in each, are reported as being inequal when using the `==` operator, and the values for `GetHashCode()` are different too.

```
byte[] id = new byte[8] {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
byte[] od = new byte[8] { 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xF8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 
};

Console.WriteLine(id == od);
Console.WriteLine(id.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(od.GetHashCode());
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output of this program to the console is as follows:

```
False
45653674
41149443
```

Can anyone offer some input as to why these byte arrays aren't considered equal?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to check if the are equal using `id.SequenceEqual(od);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can anyone offer some input as to why these byte arrays aren't considered equal?

It's very simple: array types don't override `Equals` or `GetHashCode` (or indeed `ToString`) - so you get the implementation from `System.Object`. The `Equals` implementation in `System.Object` just compares reference identity, and `GetHashCode` attempts to give a unique hash code for each object, as far as possible. You have two separate array objects, so they're unequal (the references to the objects are different) and their hash codes are unlikely to be equal either.

Array types *could* override these methods, but they don't. You could write your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` which did this though. Mind you, using an array as a hash table key would usually be a bad idea anyway, as arrays are always mutable. You'd have to be really sure that nothing would ever mutate the array, which would change the hash code.

Note that the standard collections don't override these methods either - things like `List<T>` etc.

In my experience, the most common use for comparing arrays for equality is in unit tests - and typically unit test frameworks have methods to do this for you (e.g. in a `CollectionAsserts` class). Or LINQ provides [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495305.aspx), as mentioned in other answers.

If you could tell us more about what you're trying to do, we can help you more.

Answer (score 5):

That is because `id` and `od` are two seperate arrays, with different pointers.
If you want to know if their entries are the same, you should check the equality per value.

Comment: That isn't enough in itself though - it would be entirely possible for `System.Array` to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, just like `String` does. Unfortunately for the OP, array types *don't* override those methods.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `id` and `od` point to different objects.

You can use `Enumerable` class to compare the content of the array

[`Enumerable.SequenceEqual(id, od);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)